# Procesar VARIAS selecciones de ComboBOX en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli, select

Estimados, es mi primer post en esta comunidad (y en la unica) porque realmente ya tengo mas de 3 semanas buscando una solucion y siento que es mas complicado de lo que me parecia. Voy a ser bien explicativo. Primero con lo que tengo y lo que deseo hacer  y luego el codigo.
 Tengo una pagina en donde incruste un IFRAME con un GRID en PHP. En ese Grid (como lo ven en la imagen) hay varios documentos(mas de 400). 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues si se fijan al lado de cada documento hay un COMBOBOX con la lista de custodios(personas que tiene que confirmar cada documento). Que se necesita? Que el operador de la aplicacion pueda asignarle a cada documento un custodio y luego le de al boton de procesar, para que estos cambios puedan ser enviados a la base de datos. Se supone que el operador pueda asignar 1 o mas custodios, por lo que el programa deberia de verificar cuales fueron los documentos modificados en la pagina y que vaya a la base de datos y salve los cambios segun el custio asignado.

Pense en 2 logicas: 1) almacenar los cambios en un array bidimensional, que guarde el codigo del documento y el custodios asignado. Hacer la un bucle para buscar cada documento cambiado en una base de datos y actualizarle el dato del custodio.
2) Es que cada vez que el operador haga un cambio se actualice al instante en la base de datos.Tambien hay un pequeño boton al lado del combo para ver si podia ejecutar esta tarea. Que tiene un form.

En ambos casos tengo ya 3 semanas y no logro conseguir un código que me ayude.

De verdad se lo agradecería muchísimo si alguien me puede apoyar con un código que me permita realizar los cambios en la base de datos, según la selección en el combobox.

Este es el codigo con el que lleno el combobox:

```
               echo '<form name="datosdoc" method="post" action="cssmenu/asignadoc.php">';
           echo"<select name=listausr>"; 
               for($i=0;$i<count($usuariosaasig);$i++){

                        echo '<option name="asignar" value="'.$usuariosaasig[$i].'">'.$usuariosaasig[$i].'</option>';

               } 
               echo "</select>"; 
               echo'<input type="submit" name="boton" value="º" />'; 
               echo '</form>';
```

y este es el del boton de procesar:

```
<div class="botonproc">
           <p><a href="cssmenu/asignadoc.php?varPorURL=<?php echo $docselect?>" target='tuArchivo' onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target, 'top=100% left=500% width=400, height=200, menubar=no');return false;"><input type="submit" value="Procesar.."></p> 

    </div>
```

De ante mano les agradezco mucho tu apoyo. Sea cual sea y esta demás decirles que si necesitan mas información, con gusto se las proveeré.

Answer (score 0):

Si en el select pones (PHP):

```
echo"<select name='listausr' data-docselect='$docselect'>";
```

Luego en Javascript (JQuery):

```
    $('[name="listausr"]').on('change',
      function(){
         $.get('cssmenu/asignadoc.php?varPorUrl='+$(this).attr('data-docselect')+'&usuarioPorVar='+$(this).val(),
                function(){
                     window...(pon aqui lo que quieras que haga con la respuesta de php)...
          });
      });
```

Asi (me quedo con la opcion 2) cada vez que cambie el combo llamara a 'cssmenu/asignadoc.php'

Comment: Gracias Javier, lo voy a probar....

Comment: No me funciono, pero ya consegui la respuesta y la publique! con Javascript!.

Answer (score 0):

pues gracias por el apoyo, pero consegui una solucion alternativa. 
Deje de pensar como Cliente/Servidor y pase a la logica WEB.
Primero agrege al SELECT el EVENTO ONCHANGE:

```
echo '<select id="listausr" name="listausr" onchange="ShowSelected();">';
```

Esta seria la funcion del evento ONCHANGE:

```
function ShowSelected()
    {
     /* Para obtener el valor */
     var cod = document.getElementById("listausr").value;

     /* Para obtener el texto */
     var combo = document.getElementById("listausr");
     var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
     separa ="-";
     limite=2;
     arreglocodigo=cod.split(separa,limite);
     var asignado=arreglocodigo[0];
     var folioasigna=arreglocodigo[1];
     var otrofolio=arreglocodigo[arreglocodigo.length-1];

  window.open("cssmenu/asignadoc.php?usrcust="+asignado+"&codfolio="+folioasigna, this.target, 'top=100% left=500% width=400, height=200, menubar=no')
}
```

Dentro del archivo asignadoc.php es donde capturo las variales eviadas con $_GET (o post como lo deseen) y de ahi hago la busqueda en la base de datos.
Debido a que como seleccionas una opcion en el COMBOBOX en la pagina solo queda esa dato, necesitas Recargar la pagina principal y cerrar el asignadoc.php, con eso la pagina de nuevo queda para seleccionar otro documento.

Es como un poco "trabajado", aun mas si son 450 documentos, pero fue la forma mas "solida" que consegui para resolver el tema.